# jQuery : How to operate a plugin on two input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a plug-in somewhat same like auto-complete or virtual keyboard with selected input values along with sorting and searching. This plugin is working fine to if I use it once in a page but when I apply this one to more then one then it is showing both the boxes and events are applied on the last written object. Sample code and fiddle is below:
http://jsfiddle.net/mantrig/ugmwa5b5/

my plug in code to in :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var testData = ["BSL","DSK","NPNR","SAV","ET","NDLS","JPR","MAS","BCT","NZM","BR","SUJH"];
$(".stations").myAutoSuggest({
    data:testData,
    dataref:"stationsList",
    title:"Station List",
    sort:"desc"
});
var trainData = ["12345","32151","64231","56421","78542","13452"];
$(".trains").myAutoSuggest({
    data:trainData,
    title:"Train List",
    dataref:"trainsList",
    sort:"desc"
  });
});
```

I'm very much new to writing any plug-in so code may be very dirty. A little help will be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You missed `'`. 
Change `$(body).append(html);` to `$('body').append(html);`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/ugmwa5b5/2/)

Comment: it is same both my pop-up boxes overlapped each other which is the issue here :(

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your "`selectedTextbox`" variable  change here will solve your problem

```
 $(".Help").bind("focus",function(e){
             selectedTextbox=this; 
             showVirtualHelp(selectedTextbox);
  });
```

and later using it here because there are multiple text boxes so you need to pass reference current focused element to show help box

```
function showVirtualHelp(selectedTextbox) {
            $(".virtualHelp."+settings.dataref).css("top",($(selectedTextbox).offset().top+30)+"px");
            $(".virtualHelp."+settings.dataref).css("left",($(selectedTextbox).offset().left+30)+"px");
            $(".virtualHelp."+settings.dataref).show();
    }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugmwa5b5/5/)